# WPF: Change backgroud of Grid every half second and still interact with other controls

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading

Want the background of grid be changed every half second with provided r,g,b values and still be able to interact with the buttons inside the grid.
Problem is that neither the background is changing on regualr interval nor the user is allowed to interact with the two buttons inside grid. The color of grid changes only when I switch to any other application or task manager. How to acheive?

```
<Grid Name="MainGrid" Height="{Binding ElementName=MainWindow1, Path=ActualHeight}"  Loaded="MainGrid_Loaded">
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Center">
        <Label Height="50" Name="xCoordinate" />
        <Label Height="50" Name="yCoordinate" />
        <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="50" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Content="Red" Width="100" Name="xBtn" Click="xBtn_Click" Margin="0,0,10,0"/>
            <Button Content="Blue" Width="100" Name="yBtn" Click="yBtn_Click" />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    Thread thread;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ChangeGridColor));
        thread.Start();

    }

    private void xBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        xCoordinate.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    }

    private void yBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        yCoordinate.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
    }

    private void MainWindow_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Point point = Mouse.GetPosition(Application.Current.MainWindow);
        xCoordinate.Content = point.X;
        yCoordinate.Content = point.Y;

    }

    byte r=0,g=0,b = 0;
    public void ChangeGridColor()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
            {//this refer to form in WPF application 
                MainGrid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(r, g, b));
                r += 1;
                g += 1;
                b += 1;
            }));

            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do it in code?  Use WPF's storyboards in a few lines of XAML

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a second thread just to sleep. You could use a timer. A timer calls a callback in a given interval.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer()

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();  
        _timer.Interval = 500; // 500ms.
        _timer.Elapsed += ElapsedCallback;
        _timer.Start();  
    }

    private void ElapsedCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MainGrid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(r, g, b));
        r = ++r % 0xFF; // prevent overlfow.
        g = ++g % 0xFF;
        b = ++g % 0xFF;
    }

    private void xBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        xCoordinate.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);
    }

    private void yBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        yCoordinate.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Blue);
    }

    private void MainWindow_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        Point point = Mouse.GetPosition(Application.Current.MainWindow);
        xCoordinate.Content = point.X;
        yCoordinate.Content = point.Y;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should behave as you would expect if you execute your loop on a background thread:

```
byte r = 0, g = 0, b = 0;
public void ChangeGridColor()
{
    Task.Run(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke((Action)(() =>
            {
                MainGrid.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(r, g, b));
            }));

            r += 1;
            g += 1;
            b += 1;
            Thread.Sleep(1000);
        }
    });
}
```